# Calling a function inside an other function in Js

Tags: javascript

I do not understand what am I doing wrong in it can someone explain me ?

https://jsfiddle.net/4pvhsLew/

The idea is to have a simple function of resuming text.
If the text is too long put a "..." and on click display the full length.
And then add a `span` at the end to hide it again.

So `#infoCountry` is a `<p>`element over than 200 characters.

```
if(document.getElementById("infoCountry").innerHTML.length > 200){
    function test(){
        var fullInfo = document.getElementById("infoCountry").innerHTML;
        var semiInfo = fullInfo.substring(0,200) + '<span id="plusInfo">...</span>';
        document.getElementById("infoCountry").innerHTML = semiInfo; 

        var voirPlus = document.getElementById("plusInfo");
        voirPlus.addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("infoCountry").innerHTML = fullInfo +'<span id="moinsInfo">&nbsp; Cacher</span>'; //Affiche tout et "Cacher"
            var voirMoins = document.getElementById("moinsInfo"); 
            voirMoins.addEventListener("click", test()); // HERE IS THE BUG ?
        })

    }
    test();
}
```

It work until I try to recall it. But the console stay empty. I don't understand where is the miss understanding there :/

Comment: `...addEventListener("click", test)` - pass a reference to the function, don't execute it here.

Comment: Well, you're not writing anything out to the console, for one thing.

Comment: @pawel I've just facepalmed my self...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener in Javascript triggers the click event automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489734/addeventlistener-in-javascript-triggers-the-click-event-automatically)