# My JavaScript function runs without being called

Tags: javascript, arrays, function-call

The function `tablePush` pushes an id to the table upon a click on an item.
However, it runs without a click and I don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
function tablePush() {
    console.log('OK');
    if (pickPicture) {
        console.log('TRUE');
    } else {
        console.log('on rentre dans le else');
        console.log(this);
        var idPic = this.getAttribute('id');
        console.log(idPic);
        table.push(idPic);
        pickPicture = true;
    }
}

var picture = document.getElementsByClassName('picture'),
    table = [],
    pickPicture = false;

for (var i = 0; i < picture.length; i++){
    picture[i].addEventListener('click', tablePush());
}
```

Comment: @Quentin — Better dupe target: [addEventListener in Javascript triggers the click event automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11489734/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling it.
You need to register the function `tablePush` (instead of invoking it):

```
picture[i].addEventListener('click', tablePush);
```

Answer (score 5):

The line:

```
picture[i].addEventListener('click', tablePush());
                                              ^^
```

does not add the function `tablePush`, but the result of the invocation of `tablePush()`. This is so, because the parens `()` at the end mean "invoke this function now". To correct your code, use:

```
picture[i].addEventListener('click', tablePush);
                                              ^ no parens
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function while adding event listener.

You need to update from

```
picture[i].addEventListener('click', tablePush());
```

to

```
picture[i].addEventListener('click', tablePush);
```