# Add onclick to a button with java script

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button

I am creating a list of buttons inside a table, like this:

```
let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  tbody.className = "table-responsive";
  let id = 0;
  for (let c of rows) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.className = "table";
    for (const v of c) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      td.className = "table";
      let txt = document.createTextNode(v);
      td.appendChild(txt);
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    id++;
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "ACTUALIZAR DATOS";
    button.className = "btn btn-outline-primary";
    button.id = id++;
    button.onclick = upgradePet();
    tr.appendChild(button);
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
```

the table shows correctly, but when i try to add the `.onclick`, but when the table load, it call immediately the function `upgradePet()` without me clicking it.

i try doing:

```
button.addEventListener("click", upgradePet());
button.onclick = upgradePet();
```

but both call the function when the table finish render.

Comment: Duplicate of [addEventListener in Javascript triggers the click event automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11489734/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parentesis from your `upgradePet` as that represents a function call (meaning you are not just defining the function on the click event, but you're calling it straight away).

So this works fine,

```js
button.onclick = upgradePet;
```

In case you will ever need to define functions with parameters, you can write them as followed,

```js
button.onclick = () => upgradePet(param);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentesis.

[addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

[onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

```js
button.addEventListener("click", upgradePet);
button.onclick = upgradePet;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to fix:

1. Add function objects as event listeners,  not the value returned from calling a handler function. The return value is often `undefined` or, more rarely, a boolean value:

   `element.addEventListener( eventName, handler);`   ✔️
   `element.addEventListener( eventName, handler());` ❌
2. Do not append a `<button>` element to a table row - they are not [valid child elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary) of a `<tr>` element. Create an extra `td` element, put the button element inside it and append the table data element created to the table row.